# Customise email based on recipient

Tags: c#, email, outlook, calendar, mailmessage

Using C#, I'm sending an email to a list of people who have Outlook. In that email there is a link to a shared calendar. The link looks like this:

```
<a href=\"outlook://Public Folders - joe.blogs@company.com/All Public Folders/Offices/MeetingRoomA">MeetingRoomA</a>
```

Notice that the recipient's email address forms a part of the link? That's because as of Outlook 2010, Microsoft has mandated that links to shared calendars must specify the user's email address. Article [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2470828).

For that reason, if I want to send the email to 10 people, I'm currently creating 10 emails with the following code, giving each a unique link:

```
"<a href=\"outlook://Public Folders - " + user.Address + "/All Public Folders/Offices/MeetingRoomA\">MeetingRoomA</a>"
```

This works well, but it would be nice if I could send a single email (so the recipients can see who else received the email)

Is there a way to send a single email, and have the link customized on the user's end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not using the Outlook Object Model, MAPI, or any other API exposed by OUtlook.

You ***can*** do that if you are using straight SMTP - the actual recipients are specified using the "RCPT TO" command, not by the To/CC MIME headers of the message (sent by the DATA command).

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, do you know how to set the 'To' MIME header in .net? I've asked the question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321083/send-to-a-recipient-while-listing-others-in-the-sent-to-list

Comment: I don't think MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient lets you specify "RCPT TO" command - it takes the values from the MIME message. But since the source code is available, you can modify it to use anything you want.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, it looks like it's possible without modifying the source code. I've added a link to your answer to the article that shows how. Thanks again for your help

Comment: I don't see a link. Can you add it to a comment?

Comment: It's waiting on the peer review. The link is the one in the first comment

Answer (score 1):

Continue creating a custom email for each user. Then in the MIME header, list all the people it went to. This means that each user will receive their personalised email, and will be able to see who else received the email.

To specify different values for SMTP and MIME addresses, you need an smtp library that supports it. One such library is MailKit, and here is an example of how to use it:

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("MeetingOfficeA", "noreply@office.com"));

//the following people will be in the "sent to" list, but won't receive the email
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Fidel Perez-Smith", "fidel@office.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("John Doe", "john.doe@office.com");

message.Subject = "Testing";
message.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = @"Testing 123" };

using (var client = new SmtpClient()) {
    client.Connect("smtpserver.office.com");

    //only the people in the following line will receive the email
    client.Send(message, new MailboxAddress("MeetingOfficeA", "noreply@office.com"), new [] { new MailboxAddress("Fidel Perez-Smith", "fidel@office.com") });

    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```